# Eclipse resets Java compiler compliance level to 1.7 with every restart

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse resets the compiler compliance level to 1.7 every time I restart. It kinda bothers a lot for code with large size as for every compiler compliance level change eclipse needs a fresh build

I have JDK 8 installed and have everything set to 1.8 in eclipse and project preference files.

Comment: Did you have an earlier (or newer) eclipse version? JAVA_HOME environment variable of your PC. With maven, check the user's Settoing.xml in .m2.

Comment: I have jre7 installed in a separate folder but not at all in any classpath or system environment variables. I have Java8 Home set and so do the Java8/bin set in Path

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, try to put this on your pom.xml

`<properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 </properties>`

Comment: I am using ant. I am not sure if this is something to do with ant or maven as the problem exists for a simple workspace having nothing but some simple Java code experiments without any build or dependency management tool.

Comment: I have target and source at 15, and still resets to 1.8 every time I restart eclipse.